# How to implement async function?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I would like that my function fulfilled asynchronously. I still learn to write the asynchronous code and would like to ask your help. How does such funtion have to be written?

```
class CustomerController : Controller
{

    private ICustomerRepository _customerRepository;

    public CustomerController(ICustomerRepository customerRepository)
    {
        _customerRepository = customerRepository;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        IEnumerable<CustomerViewModel> customers =
            _customerRepository.GetAllCustomers().Select(s => new CustomerViewModel
            {
                CustomerId = s.CustomerId,
                Name = s.Name,
                Adress = s.Adress
            });

        return View("Index", customers);

    }

}
```

Interface:

```
 public interface ICustomerRepository
{
    IEnumerable<Customer> GetAllCustomers();
}

    public class CustomerRepository : ICustomerRepository
    {
    private StoreDBContext _db;

    public CustomerRepository(StoreDBContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }
    public IEnumerable<Customer> GetAllCustomers()
    {
        return _db.Customers;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    IEnumerable<CustomerViewModel> customers =
        _customerRepository.GetAllCustomers().Select(s => new CustomerViewModel
        {
            CustomerId = s.CustomerId,
            Name = s.Name,
            Adress = s.Adress
        });

    return View("Index", customers);

}
```